# Transit visa 8 hour layover in Saudi Arabia

Tags: visas, transit, saudi-arabia, romanian-citizens

I am a Romanian travelling from Istanbul Turkey to Mauritius island. I have a layover of 8 hours in Jeddah (Saudi Arabia). Do I need a transit visa in Jeddah

Comment: 8 hours air-side in Jeddah? That's not something I could recommend...